# Multi-threaded algorithm to whittle queue to one element, but queue must empty mid-program

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I would like to construct an algorithm that whittles a queue down to one element but may (temporarily) empty the queue. I tried to implement this with a multinumber gcd algorithm, but it isn't working at all. I suspect the program is with the while loop, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to programming, so apologies if this is too basic a question.

```
import threading
import Queue
import time, random

#Worker Class
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, flag):
        self.__queue = queue
        self.__flag = flag
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while (queue.qsize() > 1):
            a = self.__queue.get()
            b = self.__queue.get()
            #Worker task
            g = gcd(a, b)
            if g == 1:
                flag = False
            queue.put(g)
    def quit(self):
        return

#gcd algorithm
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a

#kill all workers
def killall(workers):
    for worker in workers:
        worker.quit()

#queue starts empty
queue = Queue.Queue(0)

#input thread number
WORKERS = int(raw_input("Type in the number of threads (int > 0):"))

#input list length
k = int(raw_input("Length of integer list (int > 0):"))

#random list of integers generated
list =  [random.randint(1,1000) for i in range(k)]

while (len(list)):
    queue.put(list.pop())

#list of workers
wrkrs = []

#flag to kill if 1 is found
flag = True

#Master function
for i in range(WORKERS):
    w = Worker(queue, flag)
    wrkrs.append(w)
    w.start()

#kill process if 1 is found
if flag == False:
    killall(w)
    print "gcd is: 1"

#if this worked, answer would be the only remaining element
if queue.qsize() == 1:
    print "gcd is:", queue.get()
```

Comment: Trying to have multiple threads remove "half-jobs" from a queue like this isn't going to be safe. You'll run into problems where two threads have one number each and neither can compute a GCD. Also, checking the size of a queue is pretty much never safe.

Comment: Ah! Ok. Do you suggest I build the queue with two-element strings?

Comment: The problem is that "half-jobs" are the natural outputs of the worker threads. I suggest having a single thread receive outputs through a second queue and assemble them into two-element tuples for the workers to consume. That thread can keep track of how many tuples it has assembled and how many it expects to assemble, so it can tell when it's down to the final GCD.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you for the help.